# Can I inspect coredump on Cloud Run?

Tags: c++, c, google-cloud-run, coredump

I'm thinking about migrating some of my services from GCE VMs to Cloud Run. And I want to see how it would be like when I have to troubleshoot, especially in (hopefully rare) case that my C/C++ program segfaults.

When segfault occurs, I usually detach the VM from production and take a look at coredump, using `sudo coredumpctl gdb`.

My question is: can I do similar on Cloud Run? Can I collect coredump files and get them from somewhere like Cloud Storage?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Can I collect coredump files and get them from somewhere like Cloud
> Storage?

No. Cloud Run runs container-hosted applications. If your application throws an exception, your container will be killed.

Capturing a core dump for an application in a container requires the host operating system to be configured to enable that feature. Cloud Run does not provide access to the host platform.

Note: Cloud Run runs containers via [Knative](https://cloud.google.com/knative).

Comment: So what I can do is to try to dump any useful info before the container killed. Probably it's worth a try to wrap my program with `catchsegv`.

Comment: @ IIRC segfault will terminate your container.

Comment: What I meant by "to wrap" is to run `/usr/bin/catchsegv` as a container's entrypoint and my C/C++ program as a child process of it. `catchsegv` should be able to write some logs when its child process segfaults, before it would exit abnormally.

Answer (score -1):

In cloud run you can use [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/error-reporting) and Cloud Logging to [view an error](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/viewing-errors)

Error Reporting aggregates and displays errors produced in your running Cloud Run services. Cloud Run is automatically integrated with Error Reporting **with no setup or configuration required.**

The following errors are automatically visible:

1. All exceptions that include a stack trace in Error
   Reporting-supported languages, and that are sent to stdout, stderr,
   or to other logs.
2. "Memory limit exceeded" and "No instances available" service errors.

You can refer [this document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/error-reporting#viewing_errors_in) for viewing errors in cloud run

Comment: Do you have the list of "Error Reporting-supported languages"?  I hope C/C++ is in it.

Comment: @asari currently [Error Reporting supports](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting#:~:text=Popular%20languages&text=NET%2C%20Node.,PHP%2C%20Python%2C%20and%20Ruby.) `Go`, `Java`, `NET`, `Node.js`, `PHP`, `Python`, and `Ruby`. If you need support in C/C++ you can raise request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187271&template=1162924)